# Delete rest and reflow rest of score in MuseScore

Tags: musescore

I have a large MuseScore document from the internet that has a lot of time changes. About six hundred measures in (halfway through), there is a minor error: an extra beat of rest. This throws off the alignment of the rest of the piece — every single subsequent bar is off. I need to delete the extra rest and move the entire rest of the score one beat backward.

Is this possible, or am I up a creek?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To move everything back one beat: select from the first note after the extra beat rest to the end.   Ctrl-X.    Ctrl-C one beat earlier.

To delete the extra beat from the time-flow: select the extra beat rest, Ctrl-Delete.

Comment: Thanks! There were a lot of messed-up tuplets that made this fail at first, but once I fixed those it worked perfectly.